# How to convert class component table to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am pretty new at React Hooks and Functional Components. If anyone would be so kind as to help I would so appreciate it. I have been working at this for hours now.

How do I turn the following table that uses class components into a table that uses functional components

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: [
        { title: "Clients", view: 1, total: 20 },
        { title: "Returning Players", view: 3, total: 18 },
        { title: "New Players", view: 3, total: 20 },
        { title: "Pending Players", view: 4, total: 10 },
        { title: "Players who left", view: 3, total: 11 },
        { title: "Total Players", view: 15, total: 79 }
      ]
    };
  }

  PlayersTableHeader() {
    let header = Object.keys(this.state.status[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  }

  PlayersTableData() {
    return this.state.status.map((status, index) => {
      const { title, view, total } = status; 
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{view}</td>
          <td>{total}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table id="status">
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.PlayersTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.PlayersTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

const Table = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    status: [
      { title: "Clients", view: 1, total: 20 },
      { title: "Returning Players", view: 3, total: 18 },
      { title: "New Players", view: 3, total: 20 },
      { title: "Pending Players", view: 4, total: 10 },
      { title: "Players who left", view: 3, total: 11 },
      { title: "Total Players", view: 15, total: 79 }
    ]
  });

  const PlayersTableHeader = () => {
    let header = Object.keys(state.status[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  const PlayersTableData = () => {
    return state.status.map((status, index) => {
      const { title, view, total } = status;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{view}</td>
          <td>{total}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table id="status">
        <tbody>
          <tr>{PlayersTableHeader()}</tr>
          {PlayersTableData()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

React Hooks is a powerful tool. Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for reference

To set state in your Table Function now:

```
setState({ status: customStatus })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the functional components for readability into three different files: Your `mainfile.js` that imitates your class `Table` component above, a `playerstabledata.js` file that brings in the PlayersTableData() component and a `playerstableheader.js` file that brings in PlayersTableHeader(); Now, inside of `mainfile.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PlayersTableHeader from "./playerstableheader.js";
import PlayersTableData from "./playerstabledata.js";
const Table = (props) => {
   const [status, setStatus] = useState([
        { title: "Clients", view: 1, total: 20 },
        { title: "Returning Players", view: 3, total: 18 },
        { title: "New Players", view: 3, total: 20 },
        { title: "Pending Players", view: 4, total: 10 },
        { title: "Players who left", view: 3, total: 11 },
        { title: "Total Players", view: 15, total: 79 }
      ]);


    return (
    <div>
        <table id="status">
          <tbody>
            <tr><PlayersTableHeader status={status} /></tr>
            <PlayersTableData status={status} />
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
);
};
export default Table;
```

In `playerstableheader.js` file:

```
const PlayersTableHeader = ({status}) =>{
 let header = Object.keys(status[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
       <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });

};
export default PlayersTableHeader;
```

In `playerstabledata.js` :

```
const PlayersTableData = ({status}) => {
 return status.map(({title, view, total}, index) => {
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{view}</td>
          <td>{total}</td>
        </tr>
    });

};
export default PlayersTableData;
```

Note how you I am passing down `status` state to each component. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I like this separating of the files. I will change mine also.